# Having issues installing mySQL V 5.7x on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql

So I am going to start out by saying I have followed many websites and threads with people running into the same issues, however they never get resolved.

Everything seems to work untill I run

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04
```

and I have removed and reinstalled mysql and gone through all the options many times but everytime I run this line I get this error

```
E: Version '5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04' for 'mysql-client' was not found
```

I need to get this installed because my class is only allowed to use version 5.7, a lot of my classmates are on ubuntu v18.04 so at this point should I just downgrade to a lower version?

Or can someone help provide maybe a few different routes of attack to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu releases typically, if not always, only support one version of software that is provided via official repositories.  When it comes to MySQL, Ubuntu 20.04 provides v8.0 whereas Ubuntu 18.04 provides v5.7.

If this is a computer that is going to be used predominately for this class, you might be better off just downgrading to 18.04.  If you want to use Ubuntu 20.04, you can try using Oracle/MySQL's repository tool which claims you can pick which version of MySQL to install: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-select-series  I've never used it so I cannot speak to how well it works.